# Comparing the selected values of radio button generated dynamically through while loop and displaying score

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an exam page using php and mysql as database. I am displaying the questions and options through while loop.

The problem I am facing is to get the selected value from the user.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the code :

```
<body>
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Start Test">

<?php
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="assesment";
mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $query = "SELECT * FROM demo";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    mysql_close();
    echo "<b><center>Database Output</center></b><br><br>";
    $i=0;while ($i < $num)
    {
        $qno = mysql_result($result,$i,"qno");
        $quest = mysql_result($result,$i,"quest");
        $a = mysql_result($result,$i,"a");
        $b = mysql_result($result,$i,"b");
        $c = mysql_result($result,$i,"c");
        $d = mysql_result($result,$i,"d");
        echo "
        <br><br><b> $qno.&nbsp;&nbsp;$quest<br><br> 
        Options : </b>
        <input type='Radio' Name='Answer $qno' value='A'  >A.<span><span> $a &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='Radio' Name='Answer $qno' value='B'  >B.<span><span> $b &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='Radio' Name='Answer $qno' value='C'  >C.<span><span> $c &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type='Radio' Name='Answer $qno' value='D'  >D.<span><span> $d &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        <br><br>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you currently saving the user's selected value?

Comment: @Raiment that is where i am having trouble..Have tried a few things but nothing seems to work.. m fairly new to php so m still trying to learn..

Comment: if I could jus get help in getting the value selected by the user, that would be realy helpful.

Comment: Could you post bit more code

Comment: @Cherry I have just made the database connection and displayed the questions and answer options from the database using the code provided. trying to learn what the next step should be in order to get the selected value on submit button.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you submit the form, you will get the results from the $_GET or $_POST variable arrays. The index name is based on the `name` attribute of your `<input>` tag. So what is the code in your form handler?

Comment: @Twisty it is $_POST

Comment: In your form handler, what do you see when you do `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: @Twisty  Array ( [submit] => Start Test ) . this is what i get when print_r($_POST) is done

Comment: Can you post an example of the resulting HTML when the form is created?

Comment: I also notice that your `action` attribute is not set to anything. What page is this form posting to?

Comment: @Twisty since I am new, I am not allowed to upload an image.hence not able to send u the example of the resulting HTML page. the form displays the questions and options from the database and displays the Array ( [submit] => Start Test )  at the end.

Comment: @Twisty i was planning to display the question, options and the score calculated after submission on the same page. hence no action tag. should i redirect it to another page for the score calculation?

Comment: You can make a new http://pastebin.com/ with the resulting code. Getting just the submit suggests that the other `<input>` tags didn't get added. Also, the `action`, what is that set to?

Comment: I updated my answer now that I better understand what you're doing. Take a look, let me know if it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `mysql_*` function are deprecated and should not be used. Use MySQLi or PDO. Posting my answer with MySQLi.

I would change to a different `while` loop:

```
<body>
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Start Test"){   
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $database="assesment";
    $sql = mysqli_connect("localhost", $username, $password, $database);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM demo";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql, $query);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo "<b><center>Database Output</center></b><br><br>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $qno = $row['qno'];
        $quest = $row['quest'];
        $a = $row['a'];
        $b = $row['b'];
        $c = $row['c'];
        $d = $row['d'];
        echo "<br><br><b> $qno.&nbsp;&nbsp;$quest<br><br>\r\n"
        echo "Options : </b>\r\n";
        echo "<input type='Radio' Name='Answer[$qno]' value='A'  >A.<span><span> $a &nbsp;&nbsp;\r\n";
        echo "<input type='Radio' Name='Answer[$qno]' value='B'  >B.<span><span> $b &nbsp;&nbsp;\r\n";
        echo "<input type='Radio' Name='Answer[$qno]' value='C'  >C.<span><span> $c &nbsp;&nbsp;\r\n";
        echo "<input type='Radio' Name='Answer[$qno]' value='D'  >D.<span><span> $d &nbsp;&nbsp;\r\n"
        echo "<br><br>";
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' value='See Results'>\r\n";
    mysqli_close($sql);

} elseif(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "See Results") {
   // Review answers and show the correct ones
   foreach($_POST['Answer'] as $answer){
      // Iterate over answers...
   }
} else {
   echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Start Test'>\r\n";
}
?>
</form>
</body>
```

You may also want to consider moving your Submit Button to the end, yet as long as everything is wrapped within the `<form>` tags, it should submit the entire form.

In regards to the answers, this will depend on where you store them. But if you get them into a similar array, you can loop it and compare the results. For example:

```
} elseif(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "See Results") {
   // Review answers and show the correct ones
   $userAnswers = $_POST['Answer'];
   // Connect to DB and get Answer Key code... put in array called $keyAnswers
   $resultAnswers = array();
   for($i=0;$i<count($keyAnswers);$i++){
     if(isset($userAnswers[$i])){
       // Compare if user answered the question
       $resultAnswers[$i] = ($userAnswers[$i] == $keyAnswers[$i])?TRUE:FALSE;
     } else {
       // Answer is wrong if they did not answer it
       $resultAnswers[$i] = FALSE;
     }
   }
   foreach($resultAnswers as $k => $v){
     if($v){
       echo "You answered Question $k correctly.<br />\r\n";
     } else {
       echo "You answered Question $k incorrectly.<br />\r\n";
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you .This works. now i get  this : Array ( [Answer] => Array ( [1] => A [2] => C ) [submit] => See Results ) on print_r($_POST). can u suggest how should i store these value in a array for the purpose of comparision with database value?

Comment: This depends on where you are storing your answer key. If it's in the DB, yo uwill need to query it, stuff the answers in a similar array, and then using a `for` loop, you could compare the answers, putting the comparison results in a 3rd array with `true` or `false`. Will add to my answer a bit more.

Comment: Updated answer. You still have some work to do, not doing it all for you ;)

Comment: Also, if this has answered your question, don't forget to mark by clicking the check icon.